# avoid unwanted gap between 2 words

Tags: css, whitespace, word-wrap

```
<div style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><p class="article_content" style="margin-top: 2px;font-size: 15px;text-align: justify;color: #ffffff;margin-bottom: 2px;margin-left: 2px;width: 155px;white-space: pre-line;">Energy &amp; Natural Resources(4)</p></div>
```

screen shot of output -

[image: Screenshot]

I want to avoid extra space between 'Energy' and '&' and 'Resources'  and wrap words similar to this output.
I tried below css: `white-space: pre-line;/* white-space: pre; *//* word-wrap: break-word; *//* word-break: break-word; */` ,but still i'm seeing same output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this: `text-align: justify`